# Show only one hidden div with the same class

Tags: jquery, html, css, hidden

I have 4 hidden div with the same class .info and i want that when i click on the .show-info link will be appear only the interested div not all the .info div together.

here the code:

```
<a href="" class="show-info">Show info</a>
<div id="info">
 Info will be here...
 <a href="">close</a>
</div>

...

<a href="" class="show-info">Show info</a>
<div id="info">
 Info will be here...
 <a href="">close</a>
</div>

...

<a href="" class="show-info">Show info</a>
<div id="info">
 Info will be here...
 <a href="">close</a>
</div>

...

<a href="" class="show-info">Show info</a>
<div id="info">
 Info will be here...
 <a href="">close</a>
</div>
```

Comment: id="info"  ID should be unique

Comment: What Bala is trying to tell you is that you have to replace id="info" with class="info"

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
$('a.show-info').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).next('div.info').toggle();
});
```

But note that here i have considered `info` as a `class` since we cant have duplicate ids.

Full code,

```
 $('a.show-info').one('click', func);

 function func(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).next('div.info').show();
 }

 $('div.info a:contains(close)').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).parent().hide()
         .prev().one('click', func);
 });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JERr5/)

Comment: @FRA Select the correct `a` tags.. ignore the others while binding events/

Answer (score 1):

First you have to end anchor tag after the div and then use this code..

```
$('a.show-info').click(function(e){
 $(this).next('#info').show();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.show-info').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.info').show();
});
```

NOTE that ids must be unique, so try using class instead of id

Answer (score 0):

**ID** should be `unique` .so change html id="info" into `class="info"`

```
 $(".info").hide();
$('a.show-info').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
   $(".info").hide();
 $(this).next('div.info').show();
})
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4Wn8L/1/)

For close

```
$('a:not(.show-info):contains(close)').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
   $(".info").hide();
});
```

### [DEMO Close](http://jsfiddle.net/4Wn8L/3/)

Comment: ok thanks.
This code works but with prevent default all other <a> tag in the page doesn't woks, how can i fix?